# separate list into smaller list and go through each smaller list python

Tags: python, json, list, if-statement, for-loop

I have a list like this

```
results = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

I want to separate this list, to group items into 4elements together:

```
size = 4
group_list_4 = [results[i:i+size] for i  in range(0, len(results), size)]
print "List:" , group_list_4
```

the result of this command is this:

```
List: [[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Into each 4-group I have to check where is 1 element so if the first element on a 4group is 1 it `return "first"` if second `return "second"` till four and that value to put inside `json_obj['value_1_in_list']` .

```
lista = []
for record in records:
            json_obj = {}
            json_obj['filename'] = filename
            json_obj['value_1_in_list'] =  put element 1 on list
            lista.append(json_obj)
```

In the code above I have a list called `lista` where I create JSON obj, the condition `for record in records:` will be executed  17 times, also I have 17 small lists with 4 elements. For each time that for loop will be executed a JSON is created.
Now I want inside this `for loop` to include the value that is 1(first,second,third,fourth) inside one list of 4elements, and next time that for loop will be executed to include the other small list inside `results list` that contains 4elements how can i do that, any help?

```
Lists with four elements always contain only one 1.
```

Comment: What if there are two `1` in a list

Comment: So what's your desired output? `["first", "first", "fourth"...]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)

Comment: @JonSurrell i will return all the value that are 1

Comment: What if there are no 1's?

Comment: Just return a 'null' string @PadraicCunningham

Comment: Your question is evolving and is difficult to understand. Please try to write a clear question. And if you have a *new* follow-up question, please write a new question about that problem. Try not to avoid changing this question to include new problems.

Answer (score 2):

Using a dictionary and list's index method

**Code:**

```
test=[[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0],[0,0,0,0]]
indexer={0:"first : ",1:"two : ",2:"three : ",3:"four : "}
for val in test:
    try:
        print indexer[val.index(1)],val
    except ValueError:
        print "No 1",val
```

**Output:**

```
first :  [1, 0, 0, 0]
first :  [1, 0, 0, 0]
four :  [0, 0, 0, 1]
first :  [1, 0, 0, 0]
four :  [0, 0, 0, 1]
three :  [0, 0, 1, 0]
first :  [1, 0, 0, 0]
first :  [1, 0, 0, 0]
four :  [0, 0, 0, 1]
four :  [0, 0, 0, 1]
four :  [0, 0, 0, 1]
first :  [1, 0, 0, 0]
four :  [0, 0, 0, 1]
four :  [0, 0, 0, 1]
four :  [0, 0, 0, 1]
first :  [1, 0, 0, 0]
first :  [1, 0, 0, 0]
No 1 [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

`Warning this may not work as expected for cases where there are more then one 1 in the list and OP has not told there will be situation like that`

Comment: Your else will never be reached, if there is no 1 you will get a error

Comment: @Vignesh Kalai thank you for ur answer! now this code  how can i include that the first result to be inside json_obj['value_1_in_list']  and so on till for condition is executed ?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham why so ?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham i am checking it here `if 1 in val:` and see my output `No 1 [0, 0, 0, 0]`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes we could do that :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be implemented in a very straightforward way. You have clearly defined criteria (return a value based on an input). That is just a spec for a function. Write a function (`one_location`) and map it to your data set.

```
results = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]

size = 4
group_list_4 = [results[i:i+size] for i  in range(0, len(results), size)]

def one_location(l):
    if l[0] == 1: return "first"
    elif l[1] == 1: return "second"
    elif l[2] == 1: return "third"
    elif l[3] == 1: return "fourth"

result_list = map(one_location, group_list_4)

list(result_list)

# ['first',
#  'first',
#  'fourth',
#  'first',
#  'fourth',
#  'third',
#  'first',
#  'first',
#  'fourth',
#  'fourth',
#  'fourth',
#  'first',
#  'fourth',
#  'fourth',
#  'fourth',
#  'first',
#  'first',
#  'first',
#  'first']
```

Comment: thank you for ur answer! now this code how can I include that the first result to be inside json_obj['value_1_in_list'] and so on till for condition is executed ?

Comment: @EstinaEsitna I don't understand your question.

Answer (score -1):

```
digit_word_map = {1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: 'four'}
chunks =  [results[i:i + 4] for i in range(len(results)) if i % 4 == 0]
for chunk in chunks:
    print digit_word_map[chunk.index(1) + 1]
```

Answer (score -1):

uses [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.compress):
works for more than one `1`s in a sublist

```
>> q = ['1st','2nd', '3rd', '4th']
>> for i in range(0,len(results),4):
       f.append(compress(q,results[i:i+4]) or ["null"])

# [['1st', '4th'], ['1st'], ['4th'], ['1st'], ['4th'], ['3rd'], ['1st'], ['1st'], ['4th'], ['4th'], ['4th'], ['1st'], ['4th'], ['4th'], ['4th'], ['1st'], ['1st'], ['1st'], ['1st']]
```